# retrieving date in SELECT statement from mysql

Tags: mysql

I wrote the following mysql code:

```
select trade_dt, 
       ticker_id, 
       settle_price, 
       volume 
from hist 
where volume > 0 and trade_dt between '06/22/2011' and '06/30/2011';
```

but unfortunately, it returns dates outside the time window as follows:

```
+------------+------------+--------------+--------+
| trade_dt   | ticker_id  | settle_price | volume |
+------------+------------+--------------+--------+
| 06/23/2006 | N (Jul 06) |   156.900000 |     90 |
| 06/26/2006 | N (Jul 06) |   155.600000 |     63 |
| 06/27/2006 | N (Jul 06) |   159.300000 |     79 |
| 06/28/2006 | N (Jul 06) |   159.600000 |     57 |
| 06/29/2006 | N (Jul 06) |   143.400000 |    511 |
| 06/30/2006 | N (Jul 06) |   140.200000 |    342 |
| 06/23/2005 | V (Oct 05) |   151.200000 |     61 |
| 06/23/2011 | U (Sep 11) |    22.500000 |   6284 |
| 06/24/2011 | U (Sep 11) |    23.100000 |   4505 |
| 06/27/2011 | U (Sep 11) |    22.650000 |   3118 |
| 06/28/2011 | U (Sep 11) |    22.100000 |   3707 |
| 06/29/2011 | U (Sep 11) |    21.500000 |   5830 |
| 06/30/2011 | U (Sep 11) |    20.750000 |   9207 |
| 06/23/2008 | F (Jan 09) |    23.260000 |      2 |
```

and I wonder if that is because my trade_dt is defined as a string in hist table.EDITED table to replace char(10) with date

```
desc hist;
+-----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| futures_id      | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| trade_dt        | date          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| ticker_id       | varchar(46)   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| settle_price    | decimal(10,6) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| change_in_price | decimal(10,6) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| volume          | bigint(11)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| open_int        | bigint(11)    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

how do I fix my date problem?

ok, I changed the `trade_dt` field to `date` instead of `char(10)` and now when I run the below statement to load the data into the DB, it inserts blanks for dates, just because how the date is formatted in the data file.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '$fn' INTO TABLE $tn FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' (trade_dt,ticker_id,settle_price,change_in_price, volume, open_int);
```

this is a sample of raw data:

```
03/30/2012,Z (Dec 12),25.81,25.81,25.50,25.70,25.60,-0.45,24,0,318
```

Comment: At first - you need to store dates in the appropriate column types, such as `date`, not in `char`

Comment: I edited the table converting the `trade_dt` to `date`, but when I run the `load` statement, it inserts blanks for trade_dt. how do I cast it in the `load` statement

Comment: you need to change all your queries to pass the date in a **valid** format `YYYY-MM-DD`

Comment: can u tell me how to do that in the load statement

Comment: just change the dates in input file, there is no reason to do so in a query

Comment: millions of records, and everytime I get the data file, it is in that format....that's hardly an option

Answer (score 1):

As you note, it's because the data type is strings.  You could get the correct result by casting the column to a date type inside the query, but that's incredibly inefficient.  The only sound way to fix is to change the type of the trade_dt column, inside the table definition.

Comment: made the change, but the load statement is inserting blanks. any suggestion how I can cast my date into the valid format within the load statement

Comment: @user1155299 can't you just use a cast?  Like CAST([OLD STRING VALUE] AS DATE)

Comment: oh so I leave it as char(10) and then use CAST (trade_dt as DATE) in my SELECT statement and it returns NULL for date. so, that did not work :-(

Answer (score 0):

```
select trade_dt, ticker_id, settle_price, volume from 
hist where volume > 0 and trade_dt between '2011-06-22' and '2011-06-30';
```

MySQL retrieves and displays DATE values in 'YYYY-MM-DD' format.

Comment: This would help only if `trade_dt` was one of date-compatible types

Answer (score 0):

The problem is really with string field type.
You have two options:

- Change field to date (preferred)
- Store string dates in 'YYYY/MM/DD' format

Comment: The second option is barely an option :-S

Comment: if changing format is an appropriate solution - then there is no reason to prefer `char` over `date`

Comment: no question about it. Just pointing out a solution if for some strange reason he could not change format.

Comment: "if for some strange reason he could not change format" --- if so, then "Store string dates in 'YYYY/MM/DD' format" is not an option, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

While saving data  you get date as  dd/mm/yyyy just explode the date and save as in correct format sql accepts (YYYY-MM-DD);

```
  $date = '26/07/2001';

   $data= explode("/",$date);

    $dateField = $data[2]."-".$data[1]."-".$data[0];
```

save this  `$dateField` as date in sql table...